# Executing custom php file from Cron, implementing Wordpress mail send

Tags: php, wordpress, email, cron

I'm building a sort of selfservice portal, and need to implement it on a wordpress site. The portal itself, is build in pure php, jquery, sql etc. Without the use of the Wordpress libraries, which the rest of the main site rests on.

I've searched the web, trying to find what i need, but i couldn't find a match.

So.. What am i trying to do..

I need to run a Cron job every X day at X clock, triggering a custom PHP file in the root on the server (lets call it portal_reminder.php), which then uses the built in (or a plugin?) to send e-mails to the target specified in the custom PHP file.

Oh, as the server is hosted in a serverpark using multi-hosts, i'm not allowed to install any "external" programs (sendmail), nor can i create custom cronjobs in the terminal (cron -e).

So, i need a wordpress cron plugin to do the cron handling, aswell as wordpress/other to handle the e-mails.

For clarification, my idea was as follows:

> Cronjob triggers "portal_reminder.php"
>
> Portal reminder triggers "mailsender", including $to, $from, $content (html content)
>
> "mailsender" sends the mail :)

Is this even possible?

Comment: yes its possible. But first you test one mail send test code running in your server for testing mail sending is supported or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cron jobs works well with WordPress, even if a server cron is better. WordPress cron will trigger when someone visits your WordPress site.

Here is an example with a new schedule (WordPress native schedules are only daily, twicedaily, hourly):

```
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'wc_dsr_add_custom_cron_schedule' );
function wc_dsr_add_custom_cron_schedule( $schedules ) {
    $schedules['fourdaily'] = array(
        'interval' => 21600, // 86400s/4
        'display'  => __( 'Four time daily' ),
    );

    return $schedules;
}

function wc_dsr_create_daily_backup_schedule(){
    //Use wp_next_scheduled to check if the event is already scheduled
    $timestamp = wp_next_scheduled( 'wc_dsr_cron_send_action' );

    //If $timestamp == false schedule daily backups since it hasn't been done previously
    if( $timestamp == false ){
        //Schedule the event for right now, then to repeat daily using the hook 'wc_create_daily_backup'         
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'fourdaily', 'wc_dsr_cron_send_action' );

    }
}

//Hook our function , wc_dsr_cron_send_action(), into the action wc_dsr_cron_send_report
add_action( 'wc_dsr_cron_send_action', 'wc_dsr_cron_send_report' );

function wc_dsr_cron_send_report(){
    // do your job 
    wp_mail('test@test.com', 'Subject', 'Message');
}
```

In your case, wc_dsr_cron_send_report() might include and work with portal_reminder.php. To work well with WordPress function, you must add this to portal_reminder.php

```
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
require_once('pathto/wp-load.php);
```

You'll be able to find more example on the web.